# Modify Android Theme Programmatically

Tags: android, android-theme

A similar question to this has been asked many times; however, an answer has not been given that addresses my situation. I need to dynamically change an application's theme based on color values that are being returned from an API call. I then need to change the theme colors of the app based on the values returned. Therefore, I have no way of saving the colors in a style XML file. Can this be done?

I have a base activity, and my plan is to set the app theme from there for all the activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I did not find an easy way to do this. I created a `ThemeColor` class which holds all the colors returned by the API. Then for each activity I have to go through every widget and style it.

**Example:**

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(themeColor.getActionBarColor)));
this.getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(themeColor.getBackgroundColor()));
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to locate a simple way to resolve this issue either. By creating a ThemeColor class that holds all the colors returned from the API. Next for each activity I needed to address each widget separately as well as style it.